# What replaced Python's gnomekeyring module in Ubuntu 18.04/Bionic?

Tags: 18.04, python, gnome-keyring

I have a large set of scripts which interact with Active Directory in a corporate/enterprise environment. Rather than have to type in my AD password on each run, I built a gnomekeyring store and lookup into each script.

Now that I've upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, all of these scripts are failing because it looks like python-gnomekeyring has been [deprecated and deleted](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-python-desktop/+publishinghistory) from the archives.

What replaced it? How do I securely store a password via a python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been replaced by module `keyring` (see https://pypi.org/project/keyring/).

For Gnome Keyring, the backend of keyring can be either `SecretService` or  `Gnome.Keyring`.

```
$ keyring --list
keyring.backends.kwallet.DBusKeyringKWallet4 (priority: 3.9)
keyring.backends.kwallet.DBusKeyring (priority: 4.9)
keyring.backends.chainer.ChainerBackend (priority: 10)
keyrings.alt.Gnome.Keyring (priority: 1)
keyring.backends.fail.Keyring (priority: 0)
keyring.backends.SecretService.Keyring (priority: 5)
```

A default backend can be specified by creating `$HOME/.config/python_keyring/keyringrc.cfg` with

```
[backend]
default-keyring=keyring.backends.SecretService.Keyring
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the answer is [`libsecret`](https://developer.gnome.org/libsecret/0.16/migrating-locking.html)

However, it also appears that some functionality has been removed.

> In libsecret you can unlock items directly, and the result is (with
>   gnome-keyring daemon) that the enclosing collection will be unlocked.
>
> It is no longer possible to pass a password to unlock keyrings. These
>   are automatically prompted for.